# Cummulative Tax Calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a calculator to calculate taxes. I already have an input asking whether they are single, married, etc. and how much they earn. I have already calculated which bracket they fall into. What I am having trouble with is the cumulative percentages. Y'know, 'the first 9,325 of your salary is 10%, the next 37,950 is 15%' etc.. I'm trying to use a

```
for income in range(0, 9325):
```

But if you put in, say 9326, it will jump to the next bracket. Anyway, this is my current code (well, the main function of it. You can find the whole thing at https://repl.it/@Sphelix/FlusteredClumsyDemo ):

```
if thing == "1" and income <= 9325:
 print("Your tax rate is 10%")
elif thing == "1" and income <= 37950:
 print("Your tax rate is 15%")
elif thing == "1" and income <= 191650:
 print("Your income is 28%")
elif thing == "1" and income <= 416700:
 print("Your tax rate is 33%")
elif thing == "1" and income <= 418000:
 print("Your tax rate is 35%")
elif thing == "1" and income >= 418001:
 print("Your tax rate is 39.6%")
```

Comment: What is the variable `thing` used for?

Comment: the type of filing status (single, married etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loops are not usually used for checking ranges. Comparison operators (`<, >, <=, >=`) are used for this type of task. In your case, income is a float, so there are `9325 * 2**64` checks that you must do if you want to use a for loop to check all possible incomes. But if you want to make it work, you can do

```
import struct

def reinterpretAsInt(f):
    return struct.unpack('Q', struct.pack('d', f))[0]

def reinterpretAsFloat(n):
    return struct.unpack('d',struct.pack('Q', n))[0]

for testIncome in range(0,reinterpretAsInt(9325)):
    # print('Checking income amount: ' + str(reinterpretAsFloat(testIncome)))
    if income == reinterpretAsFloat(testIncome):
        print("Your tax rate is 10%")
        break
```

If you run this code, you will realise how inefficient it is to check each possible income level using a for loop. You should be using comparison operators for this type of problem. Your current code is fine, but you could condense all the `thing == "1"` checks into a single `if` statement.

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: @Sinjin Are you talking about the code block containing the for loop? That was an example of what to not do. But if you want to test it out, make a new project and choose a test variable for `income`.